# How to sort nested array of objects by date

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am creating simple News application, And i am using Firebase as back-end, I have stored News articles in Cloud firestore, In my fields i have News publication time `hr:min:sec` I want to sort received data by publication time, from the latest to the oldest, any solutions? Thanks in advance

```js
var data = [ 
    { news: [ 
          { published_at: "2/22/2021",
           imgUrl: "", 
           id: 159783, 
           title: "short descr", 
           date: "18:11:53", 
           previewText: "some kind of title" } 
           ], 
          newsId: "5GTAbGLfS0hSCOkmTfHD" 
       }, 

       
           
      { news: [ 
          { id: 159783,
           published_at: "2/22/2021", 
           previewText: "some kind of title2",
            title: "short descr", 
            date: "17:19:53", 
            imgUrl: "" 
            } 
         ], 
      newsId: "lw2hzVe0m3dbcmvBj4Vz" } 
  ]

  data.forEach((item)=>{
      var singleItem = item.news
     const finalResult = singleItem.sort((a, b) => b.date - a.date)
     console.log(finalResult)
  })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`string#localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) to sort time in `hh:mm:ss` format.

```js
const data = [ { news: [ { published_at: "2/22/2021", imgUrl: "", id: 159783, title: "short descr", date: "18:11:53", previewText: "some kind of title" } ], newsId: "5GTAbGLfS0hSCOkmTfHD" }, { news: [ { id: 159783, published_at: "2/22/2021", previewText: "some kind of title2", title: "short descr", date: "17:19:53", imgUrl: "" } ], newsId: "lw2hzVe0m3dbcmvBj4Vz" } ];
data.sort((a,b) => b.news[0].date.localeCompare(a.news[0].date));
console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like this

```
const finalResult = singleItem.sort((a, b) => Date.parse(`${b.published_at} ${b.date}`) - Date.parse(`${a.published_at} ${a.date}`))
```